1 of my services in my docker compose file is not taking any configs
I have a Docker Compose file with 5 services, a volumes section with 4 volumes, and a custom network section. It uses environment variables and a .env file. Here’s the structure:
version: '3.8'
name: webapp

services:
  redis:
    image: utopia:5000/redis
    hostname: ${HOSTNAME}
    networks:
      webui:
        ipv4_address: 172.17.0.3

  scheduler:
    image: utopia:5000/scheduler:${TAG}
    hostname: ${HOSTNAME}
    dns_search:
      - ${DNSDOMAINNAME}
    restart: on-failure:5
    depends_on:
      - engine
    networks:
      webui:
        ipv4_address: 172.17.0.4
    volumes:
      - sw:/sw
      - decks:/var/decks
      - list:/var/share
      - /dev/log:/dev/log

  celery:
    image: utopia:5000/celery:${TAG}
    hostname: ${HOSTNAME}
    dns_search:
      - ${DNSDOMAINNAME}
    restart: on-failure:5
    depends_on:
      - scheduler
    networks:
      webui:
        ipv4_address: 172.17.0.5
    volumes:
      - sw:/sw
      - decks:/var/decks
      - list:/var/share
      - /dev/log:/dev/log

  webgui:
    image: utopia:5000/webgui:${TAG}
    hostname: ${HOSTNAME}
    dns_search:
      - ${DNSDOMAINNAME}
    restart: on-failure:5
    depends_on:
      - celery
    networks:
      webui:
        ipv4_address: 172.17.0.7
    volumes:
      - sw:/sw
      - decks:/var/decks
      - list:/var/share
      - /dev/log:/dev/log

  engine:
    image: utopia:5000/engine:${TAG}
    hostname: ${HOSTNAME}
    dns_search:
      - ${DNSDOMAINNAME}
    restart: on-failure:5
    depends_on:
      - redis
    networks:
      webui:
        ipv4_address: 172.17.0.2
    volumes:
      - sw:/sw
      - decks:/var/decks
      - list:/var/share
      - /dev/log:/dev/log

volumes:
  sw:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: nfs
      o: ${SWADDR}
      device: "${SWDEVICE}"
  list:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: nfs
      o: ${LISTADDR}
      device: "${LISTDEVICE}"
  decks:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: ${DECKS}
      o: bind

networks:
  webui:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.17.0.0/24

All services start correctly except for engine, which does not get the assigned IP address, hostname, or volumes mounted. When I inspect the service with docker inspect, all the values are present but not reflected in the running container.
Here are the troubleshooting steps I’ve tried:

Ensured consistent whitespace in the YAML file.
Changed the order of services in the file.
Tried using only engine and its dependent service.
Replaced environment variables with hard-coded values.

Interestingly, if engine is the only service in the file, it gets the correct values. What could be causing this issue and how can I resolve it?

You can probably safely delete all of the networks:, hostname:, and dns_search: options in the file; Compose's defaults for these work fine for most applications, and you typically want to avoid manually assigning IP addresses.  At least some of these are implicated in your issues, does deleting them help at all?

If I delete them, the application won't work at all. There's also not a duplicate address. I can bring everything up with the same settings by invoking "docker run " on each individual container. It just doesn't work with compose. But I think compose is doing the right thing, based on the info in "docker inspect"

So the build process used podman -build --no-squash. I removed the no-squash and the problem went away...

If the IP address is not assigned, then most probably it is already taken. Have you tried to set a different IP address? You may also try a different CIRD, e.g. 172.17.10.0/24.

So rebuilding without --no-squash solved the issue. I have no idea why.
